# how use loading gif in apex pages?

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-apex

i want use loading gif in apex pages when doing a query:
i have a button and behind of it i use dynamic action for executing a query, in attributes of page in javascript section, i wrote these:
`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js`
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js`
and in css section, in inline, i wrote these:

```
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url(#APP_IMAGES#Preloader_1.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

and finally, behind of my button, in dynamic action , i created a true action (execute javascript code) and i wrote these:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```

after that, i created another true action (execute pl/sql code) for doing my query.

i expected when i clicked button, i saw gif loading until my query went done, but i didn`t it and i haven`t any error.

what is my mistake?

thank you

Comment: the loading image is faded out after the loading finishes. Do you bring it to the output when you actually trigger the action by clicking the button?

Answer (score 1):

Did you know there's a built-in API for this? Just call `apex.util.showSpinner`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aexjs/apex.util.html#.showSpinner

You can then call `remove` on the object returned.

Here's an example from the doc:

```
var lSpinner$ = apex.util.showSpinner($( "#container_id"));

// Then later...
lSpinner$.remove();
```